# Status message with like and comments count

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to fetch most like status of a user. I have checked the FQL docs.I can get the status by particular time. However I am unable to find the most liked status of a user using following snippet

```
SELECT status_id FROM status WHERE uid = me() ORDER BY status_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I can't loop the comments or like table for every status id to find the most liked status.
So I guess I am missing something in the FQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the likes information using the `status` table. Use the [`stream`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) table instead. A `type` of 46 restricts the results to just status updates.

```
SELECT message, description, post_id, likes FROM stream 
 WHERE source_id=me() AND type=46 ORDER BY likes.count DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: type = 46 is the key! Where can i find the list of types?

Comment: The [stream table documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) has the most common of them. Others you'll just need to query the stream table for a particular post and see what type gets returned.